# Restriction of the Frobenius automorphism for normal extensions

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, normal-extension

I'm studying number theory on Marcus book and at a
 certain point I'm required to prove the following facts about the Frobenius automorphism.

We start with a lemma and then are required to specialize it

> **Lemma**: Let K be a number field, and L,M two finite extensions of it, let now P, Q, U, V be primes in K, M, L ,ML such that Q, U lie over P and V lies over Q and U.
>   Then if P is unramified in M $\phi(V|Q)$ restricted to M is equal to $\phi(U|P)^{f(Q|P)}$

Let now $$\begin{matrix} K&\subset& L&\subset& M&\\ \cup & & \cup && \cup\\ P&\subset& Q&\subset& U\end{matrix} $$, here P is unramified in M so that we can use the lemma.

I want to prove the following two things:

1. $\phi(U|Q)=\phi(U|P)^{f(Q|P)}$
2. If L is normal of K then $\phi(Q|P)$ is the restriction of $\phi(U|P)$ to L.

I don't really get what is meant by *restriciton to []* and so I'm finding hard to find an answer to my questions.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first statement you have to prove is related to the property of the norm of the ideal $P$, we have that, since $Q$ lies over $P$, $||Q||=||P||^{f}$ (This happens because P is unramified, so $PO_L=Q_1\cdots Q_r$ then $||PO_L||=||P||^{rf}=||Q||^{r}$).
For the second point, you have $\phi (U|P)$ and $\phi (Q|P)$ the first morphism acts (comes from a morphism of the Galois group) on the field $O_M/U$ sending an element $a$ to $a^{||P||}$. The second morphism does the same thing but acts on the field $O_L/Q$. What you have to prove is, when you know that a morphism of the first group is associated to a certain morphism in the Galois group, you take this last one and restrict to $L$. Now you check whether or not this morphism in the new galois group correspond to the automorphism of the finite field you were looking for.